# Pytorch lightning logger doesn't work as expected

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, pytorch-lightning

Good evening,

I am a beginner in Pytorch lightning and I am trying to implement a NN and plot the graph (loss and accuracy) on various sets.

The code is this one

```
def training_step(self, train_batch, batch_idx):
    X, y = train_batch 
    y_copy = y # Integer y for the accuracy
    X = X.type(torch.float32)
    y = y.type(torch.float32)  
    # forward pass
    y_pred = self.forward(X).squeeze()  
    # accuracy
    accuracy = Accuracy()
    acc = accuracy(y_pred, y_copy)
    # compute loss
    loss = self.loss_fun(y_pred, y)
    self.log_dict({'train_loss': loss, 'train_accuracy': acc}, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss

def validation_step(self, validation_batch, batch_idx):
    X, y = validation_batch
    X = X.type(torch.float32)
    # forward pass
    y_pred = self.forward(X).squeeze()        
    # compute metrics 
    accuracy = Accuracy()
    acc = accuracy(y_pred, y)
    loss = self.loss_fun(y_pred, y)
    self.log_dict({'validation_loss': loss, 'validation_accuracy': acc}, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss


def test_step(self, test_batch, batch_idx):
    X, y = test_batch
    X = X.type(torch.float32)
    # forward pass
    y_pred = self.forward(X).squeeze()        
    # compute metrics   
    accuracy = Accuracy()
    acc = accuracy(y_pred, y)
    loss = self.loss_fun(y_pred, y)
    self.log_dict({'test_loss': loss, 'test_accuracy': acc}, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss
```

After training the NN, I run this peace of code:

```
metrics = pd.read_csv(f"{trainer.logger.log_dir}/metrics.csv")
del metrics["step"]
metrics
```

and I obtain this
[image]

It is okay than on the validation set there's only one accuracy and one loss, because I am performing an hold out CV. On the test set, I noticed that the value `test_accuracy=0.97` is the mean of all the accuracy for each epoch. with that I can't see the intermediate values (for each epoch) and then I can't plot any curve. It would be useful also when I'll do a cross validation with KFold.

Why he's taking the mean and How can I see the intermediate results ? For the `training_step` it works properly, I can't figure out why the logger doesn't perform the same print for the `test_step`.

Can someone help me please ?